# Help me troubleshoot installing my network adapter (Edimax 7318usg) on OS X

Tags: macos, networking, troubleshooting, network-adapter

I've recently purchased an Edimax 7318usg but it isn't co-operating with my Mac.

Has anyone installed this network adapter on OS X before?  I cannot get it to show under the networks tab of System Preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true.  I had tried several things, been in touch with customer service for a few weeks and today they released a new patched driver to solve this issue.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Drivers installed?

http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=8&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44

AFAIK, USB wifi adaptors aren't out of the box supported with OS X.